# android kills my phonegap app

Tags: android, cordova, knockout.js

Our application is a phonegap rendered website that uses google maps api inside an iframe, 
and after 20 minutes of runtime android kills the application
only after we disabled the iframe (with google map inside it) did the killing stop.
we are using knockout as framework

how does android mark a process for killing?
how does google maps control trigger android to kill my app?

does anyone have any thoughts or ideas?
please feel free to comment.

we checked for memory leaks but there arent any

Comment: When it needs to free resources.

Comment: we have no memory leak

Comment: are you testing inside an emulator? how about trying it on a real device. if its not killed on a device, then it might be using a lot of resources since emulators cannot handle as much as resources as real devices can.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to fill you in,
we are checking the possibility of memory leak on the google maps control (after all the application doesn't crash immediately but only after 20 minutes)
one thing that triggered the idea of memory leak aside from crash after 20 minutes only, 
is the amount of posts on memory leaks on the google maps control, apparently the leak is caused by markers or polilines as described [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers#markerclusterer).

well, see you soon after this test